Не подлючается заголовочный файл
Всем привет. Использую VS 2022. При написании класса Array столкнулся с проблемой: у меня не вызывается конструктор моего класса. При запуске программы выдаёт ошибку 

Файлы лежат в одной папке, к мэйну и Array.cpp я подключаю Array.h вот так:
#include "Array.h"
Как я понял, дело в том, что у меня не подключается заголовочный файл и я не могу понять почему. К слову, когда я меняю #include "Array.h" на #include <Array.h> компилятор выдаёт следующие ошибки
Я пробовал ставить полный путь, исправить проблему это не помогло, не знаю в чём может быть дело. Добавлю если Вам что-то понадобится

С инклудами похоже все в норме.(возможно в файл проекта не добавлены)
У Вас ошибка компоновщика - конструктор/деструктор неопределены.
Судя по сигнатуре класс является шаблоном.
Предположу, что Вы пытались вынести методы в отдельный файл.
С шаблонами так не проходит(обычно. спец случаи не рассматриваю).
Разместите всесь код template в заголовочном файле.
